# Transfer Column and its contents from one Table to another

Tags: sql

I am in a serious pickle.
So i have 2 tables with very similar data.

Table 1 has the following columns: FirearmID, Manufacturer, ParentCategory, Category, Series, Model, Version, MfgPartNumber, ImageSetID, FirearmDescriptionID, LastUpdate

Table 2 has the following columns: MDL_ID, Manufacturer, ParentCategory, Category, Series, Model, Version, MfgPartNumber

Now rows in both tables contain the exact same information in their columns sequentially ie, row1 in table 1 is the same as row1 in table2, for the columns that are named the same e.t.c

**example:** row1 in table1 has the same data in the Manufacturer, ParentCategory, Category, Series, Model, Version, MfgPartNumber, columns that row1 in table2 has

My question is, how can i import the MDL_ID column in table2, into table1?

**Note1: FirearmID in table1 and MDL_ID in table2 are not the same**

**Note2: Also, FirearmID increments sequentially, i.e starts with 1 and increments by a factor of 1, whereas MDL_ID does not increment sequentially.**

Comment: When you say "Row1 in table1 is the same as Row1 in table2", row 1 ordered by what?

Comment: @TabAlleman, row1 in table1 is the same as row1 in table2 sequentially, just as row233 in table1 is the same as row233 in table2.

Comment: Rows are not stored sequentially in tables .   Tables are un-ordered sets.   Unless you have a column to order by reliably, there is no way to relate row233 in one table to row233 in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the MDL_ID column from table 2 into table 1, update the value of MDL_ID in table1 based on the data in the other columns that match.

```
Update t1
set t1.MDL_ID = t2.MDL_ID
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.Manufacturer = t2.Manufacturer
and t1.ParentCategory = t2.ParentCategory
and t1.Category = t2.Category
etc...
```

`